# How can I check object equality in object array with using array includes function?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, equality

I want to check an array has the object which given as parameter to js includes function. For example:

```
let arr = [
    {'name': 'max', 'age': '20'},
    {'name': 'max', 'age': '21'},
    {'name': 'jane', 'age': '22'}];
console.log(arr.includes({'name': 'max', 'age': '21'})); // FALSE
```

That give me "false" value. How can I check object equality in object array without for loop eq.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a generic function like

```
let matches = flt => x => Object.keys(flt).every(k => flt[k] === x[k]);
```

and then

```
arr.some(matches({'name': 'max', 'age': '21'}))
```

This performs shallow, partial comparison. If you need other modes, like full and/or deep comparison, this would be far more tricky to implement. I'd suggest using lodash (`_.isMatching`, `_.isEqual`) in this case.

Comment: Huh. I like this one more than mine, well done. Is there any reason for using `keys` instead of `entries`? I mean, I'm pretty sure it would be the same, just wondering.

Comment: @briosheje: no particular reason, except that `keys` is slightly wider supported.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot do this with `includes` because you don't handle the equality check and the objects are different, therefore, nothing matches.

To do what you want, you can use `some` or `find` !

```js
let arr = [
    {'name': 'max', 'age': '20'},
    {'name': 'max', 'age': '21'},
    {'name': 'jane', 'age': '22'}
];

console.log(arr.some(({name, age}) => name === 'max' && age === '21'));
console.log(!!arr.find(({name, age}) => name === 'max' && age === '21'));
```

Please note that `find` returns the object, I've added `!!` to print a boolean result, but that's not necessarily mandatory.

Comment: If you know the structure of your object, it's keys to be exact then you can go ahead with sjahan's solution.

Comment: As `some` and `find` takes a function in parameter, you can easily implement any 'equality check function' that you want/need.
Although, working not knowing what you handle/compare will likely have a perf cost. Having a 'universal' compare function that deeps into both objects is cool but could be expensive.
If this does not answer your question, let me know and i'll delete it.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way to achieve the same result :

If the structure of the object is not known well in before, i.e when they change dynamically, from an API or something then you can use the following solution

```js
let arr = [
    {'name': 'max', 'age': '20'},
    {'name': 'max', 'age': '21'},
    {'name': 'jane', 'age': '22'}
];


let x =   {'name': 'max', 'age': '20'};
let result =arr.map( ele => JSON.stringify(ele)).includes(JSON.stringify(x));
console.log(result)
```

The above solution will work for nested objects as well.

**Note** 
The solution has two caveats

1. It works provided that order of your keys remain constant throughout the array as well in the `x` object, the one which you wish to compare
2. If there is too much of nesting in your objects then it will be really slow. I won't recommend JSON.stringify for anyone who care about performance.

**Edit 1**

3. Doesn't work with Circular structures

Comment: You can add: **3. Doesn't work with Circular structures`**

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option relying on both `.some` and `.entries` to ensure that all the `key-value` pairs passed exists and are matched inside the targeted array.
This also will ignore the order of the keys, and accepts a dynamic input.

This example assumes that if fewer keys are provided, only these are checked. For example, checking for `{'name': 'max'}` only will return true.

```js
let arr = [
    {'name': 'max', 'age': '20'},
    {'name': 'max', 'age': '21'},
    {'name': 'jane', 'age': '22'}];

function includedInArray(lookups, _arr) {
  // Ensure every lookup match.
  return _arr.some(i => {
    // Loop key-value pairs.
    return Object.entries(lookups).every(([key, value]) => {
      return i[key] === value;
    });
  });
};

console.log(includedInArray({
  'name': 'max',
  'age': '21'
 }, arr)); // should return true.
 
 console.log(includedInArray({
  'age': '21',
  'name': 'max'
 }, arr)); // should return true.
 
 console.log(includedInArray({
  'age': '55',
  'name': 'max'
 }, arr)); // should return false.
 
 console.log(includedInArray({
  'name': 'max'
 }, arr)); // should return true.
```